# xcode file automatically changed - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Everyday i run my project and it works fine but unfortunately today when i tried to run the project it shows alot of error with locked file, the code has automatically changed, this is the two file where the error show TZStackView.swift and PageView.swift

the code for TZStackView.swift file is:

```
fileprivate func constraint(item view1: AnyObject, attribute attr1: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute, relatedBy relation: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation = .equal, toItem view2: AnyObject?, attribute attr2: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute? = nil, multiplier: CGFloat = 1, constant c: CGFloat = 0, priority: Float = 1000) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

    let attribute2 = attr2 != nil ? attr2! : attr1

    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: attr1, relatedBy: relation, toItem: view2, attribute: attribute2, multiplier: multiplier, constant: c)
    constraint.priority = priority // the error show here which is Replace 'constraint.priority = priority' with 'UILayoutPriority(rawValue: constraint.priority = priority) ?? <#default value#>'


    return constraint
}
```

and for PageView.swift file :

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    let topAnchors = [
        topStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: topContainerOffset),
        topStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -topContainerOffset),
        topContainerAnchor,
        topContainerHeightAnchor
        ].flatMap { $0 }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(topAnchors)
} else {
    let topAnchors = [
        topStackView.anchors.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(anchors.leadingAnchor, constant: topContainerOffset),
        topStackView.anchors.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(anchors.trailingAnchor, constant: -topContainerOffset),
        topContainerAnchor,
        topContainerHeightAnchor
        ].flatMap { $0 }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(topAnchors)
}

// StackViews common setup
topStackView.axis = .vertical
topStackView.alignment = .center
topStackView.distribution = .fill
topStackView.spacing = -10 // TODO: Make inspectable

// Add subviews to the top StackView
topStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
topStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)

// Intial setup for top StackView subviews
imageView.isOpaque = true
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35)
titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
titleLabel.text = pageTitle
//titleLabel.backgroundColor = .redColor()

// This way the StackView knows how to size & align subviews.

imageView.setContentHuggingPriority(250, for: .vertical) // the error shows here which is Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UILayoutPriority'

titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(252, for: .vertical) // and here
```

}

Comment: “the code has automatically changed” It seems more likely that you updated Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that it is expecting a value of type `UILayoutPriority` for both `constraint.priority` and for `setContentHuggingPriority` instead of Int or Float. You can use the following constructor of `UILayoutPriority` where you can pass in a float value and get the expected type. `init(rawValue: Float)` which in your case would be as below:

`constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: priority)`

Refer to apple docs for more detail:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526946-priority

Comment: and what about   imageView.setContentHuggingPriority(250, for: .vertical) it is showing error Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UILayoutPriority'

Comment: Yes, because it requires UILayoutPriority as well. You need to understand the type it is expecting and read official documents. 
`imageView.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250.0), for: .vertical)`